# Is possible to join executions with different parameters requirements into just one execution?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a bunch of test cases and I need to execute just one under different conditions.
Also I have a variables file, which has by default some values and that specific test case needs a variation on one of those; let's say I have the following file *variables.txt*:

```
# variables.txt
user:myUser@soverflow.com
pass:mypass123
status:active
```

Also I have a Keywords file (*setup_keywords.robot*) that is used by the "Suite Setup" for the execution of the test cases.

```
#setup_keywords.robot
*** Variables ***
${user}     any@any.com
${pass}     anypass.123
${status}   hold
*** Keywords ***
Setup Start Configuration
```

Then, I have the folder with several files, and several test cases in each file, so, let's suppose that test case is in *my_tcs9.robot*:

```
# my_tcs9.robot
*** Setinges ***
# import libraries
Library           Collections
Library           RequestsLibrary
Library           blablabla
Resources         ../bla/bla/bla

# Then here's the problematic keyword:
Suite Setup       Setup Start Configuration

*** Test Cases ***
My Test Cases
    [Tags]    ALL_TESTS_TAG    UNIQUE_TAG
    Any Keywords to execute

More Test Cases 1
    [Tags]    ALL_TESTS_TAG    UNIQUE_TAG1
    Any Keywords to execute

More Test Cases 2
    [Tags]    ALL_TESTS_TAG    UNIQUE_TAG2
    Any Keywords to execute

More Test Cases etc
    [Tags]    ALL_TESTS_TAG    UNIQUE_TAG_ETC
    Any Keywords to execute
```

Finally to execute I use a command line for each situation:
To execute all test cases:
`python -m robot --include ALL_TESTS_TAG -A folder1/variables.txt`

To execute the specific configuration one:
`python -m robot --include UNIQUE_TAG -A folder1/variables.txt -v status:new`

I've been doing some research but, I guess it is a very specific situation, that I couln't find something like that.

Comment: I have a similar situation. My workaround is to run the robot several times, saving to a different output file. When all runs are done, I use rebot to combine output xmls.

Comment: Thanks, @Pekka!
It worked... also I tested with keyword [Arguments], which I added to the specific test cases `Setup Start Configuration` and think it was easier solution... When you actively send the a value through arguments to the keyword, it is respected by the robot command despite it is sending actively a variable, in this case **status=active**:
Something like this:
\n`Any Keywords to execute    status=active`